# find all :conditions id found in an array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models (`player` and `team` linked through the model `lnkteamplayer`)

```
Team has_many players through lnkteamplayer
Player has_many teams through lnkteamplayer
```

I need to retrieve all players not belonging to a specific team.

```
<% @players = Player.find(:all, :conditions => ["id != ?",@team.lnkteamplayers.player_id ]) %>
```

I am getting an error with above line of code. My question is how do i pass an array of values in the above condition.

Thanks for any suggestion provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems there:

1) the first part of conditions, "id != ?", is a fragment of sql, and in sql you do "not equals" as `<>` not `!=`.  Eg `"id <> ?"`

2) To use an array, the sql syntax is `id in (1,2,3)` or `id not in (1,2,3)`.  In your conditions you can do this like `:conditions => ["id not in (?)", array_of_ids]`

So, you could get players not on a team like this:

```
@team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
@not_on_team = Player.find(:all, :conditions => ["id not in (?)", @team.player_ids])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided an error message, I am kind of guessing here. However, I don't think `!=` is a valid syntax in many SQL dialects. You are probably looking for something like `NOT IN ()` instead.

Also, `@team.lnkteamplayers.player_id` probably doesn't work since the value returned from `@team.lnkteamplayers` likely doesn't have a `player_id` method; you might want the ids of the actual players instead.

That can be done using something like `@team.lnkteamplayer_ids`.

All in all, your line probably needs to look like

```
<% @players = Player.find(:all, :conditions => ["id NOT IN (?)", @team.lnkteamplayer_ids]) %>
```

but without more information we can't say for sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion but i have 2 fields in the 'lnkteamplayers' table representing the player id and the team id. If i do something like :

Comment: @Jakob S - That's going to match player ids against lnkteamplayer ids, and therefore not work...

Comment: @players = Player.find(:all, :conditions => ["id NOT IN (?)", @team.lnkteamplayers[0].player_id])

Comment: @tanya - that's going to get all players except the first member of the team. Which isn't what you want either.  Also, `@team.lnkteamplayers[0].player_id` gives a single id and you need to pass an array.  See my answer...

Comment: the above line of code returns me a list of players not not containing the first player in the @team. In fact i want a list of players not containing all the players in the @team

Comment: @tanya - you talking to me? :)

Comment: @max-williams You're right, I missed the fact that lnkteamplayers was the through part of a has_many association. Your answer is better.